# Make sysctl changes at startup

Tags: high-sierra, launchd, startup, daemons

I'd like to change the default smb settings at startup to remove timeouts. I have the following script;

```
#!/bin/sh

sysctl net.smb.fs.kern_deadtimer=0
sysctl net.smb.fs.kern_hard_deadtimer=0
sysctl net.smb.fs.kern_soft_deadtimer=0
```

Running this script with `sudo` sets the relevant kernel options correctly. So I know that these commands are the correct ones.

I have created the following LaunchDaemon in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` to try and get this script to run at startup;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.jo.sysctl</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/admin/scripts/sysctl.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've checked the plist with `plutil` and it checks out OK. I've set the permissions on the shell script to `0755` and set ownership of the plist file to `root:wheel`.

Running

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jo.sysctl.plist
```

...does nothing. The defaults are still set incorrectly. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use the whole path to `sysctl`.

Comment: /private/etc/sysctl.conf should still work in High Sierra! (`man sysctl.conf`)

Comment: @Allan `/Users/admin/scripts/sysctl.sh` is the whole path?

Comment: @klanomath I tried this before the LaunchDaemon option but it didn't work! Think it doesn't work because sysctl doesn't set the smb parameters until the first smb connection is made, and then it defaults to the usual (crappy) ones. Would appreciate any insight on this point however.

Comment: No, not your script, but the path to the *command* `sysctl` - `/usr/bin/sysctl`

Comment: @Allan I modified the script but this didn't work. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: To see whats happening, append the following to each `sysctl` command - `2>&1 >> /Users/admin/myscript.log ` So, your command should be `/usr/bin/sysctl net.smb.fs.kern_deadtimer=0 2>&1 >> /Users/admin/myscript.log`  This way, you can see what message and error message are being generated, if any.

Comment: *.deadtimer are all "sysctl: unknown oid \*.deadtimer" in my High Sierra environment. IE they don't exist!

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best to ditch the script approach and use the settings file designed for this purpose: sysctl.conf

<sub>This applies up to macOS 10.12 Sierra.

as @klanomath pointed out in comments: " *.deadtimer are all "sysctl: unknown oid *.deadtimer" in my High Sierra environment. IE they don't exist!"

So it looks like that part of the sysctl interface is completely gone now.</sub>

```
sudo nano  /private/etc/sysctl.conf
```

add the following variables:

```
net.smb.fs.kern_deadtimer=0
net.smb.fs.kern_hard_deadtimer=0
net.smb.fs.kern_soft_deadtimer=0
```

If you afterwards boot in verbose mode (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on startup or `sudo nvram boot-args="-v"` before a reboot), you should see the custom settings being applied.

You should then see on boot messages like these:

```
net.smb.fs.kern_deadtimer: 60 -> 0
net.smb.fs.kern_hard_deadtimer: 600 -> 0
net.smb.fs.kern_soft_deadtimer: 30 -> 0
```

Otherwise check with

```
sysctl -a | grep smb
```

This approach should work for most settings that are accessible via sysctl and thus be as generalised as the question title implies.

Comment: In the comments, the OP said they tried this method and it didn't work.

Comment: The whole net.smb.* tree vanished. So I would rather write "the kernel states are gone" than "that part of the sysctl interface is completely gone" ;-)

Comment: I'm testing on machines running macOS Sierra and High Sierra. Running `sysctl -a | grep smb` returns the same output. So I'm not sure it's correct to assert that "the sysctl interface is completely gone now". 
In my testing I noticed that all references to smb* disappeared AFTER I started making changes to /etc/sysctl.conf and rebooted. However the same settings would reappear as soon as I opened an smb connection...

Comment: Indeed, I believe that the reason creating/editing `/etc/private/sysctl.conf` does **not** work is because the smb service does not start until you initiate an smb connection (I believe...).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this in the end.

The trick was to set a longer default timeout value in `/etc/nsmb.conf` like so:

```
[default]
max_resp_timeout=1000     # default is 30 which way too low!
```

Thanks everyone for all your help :-)